# How many number of elements can be sorted in Θ(log n) time using heap sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, heapsort

How many number of elements can be sorted in Θ(log n) time using heap sort?

When we do a heapsort, to build the heap we need Θ(n) complexity and then to do the heapsort O(nlog n). I understand this concept. But when it comes to our question here, we can not even build a heap of n elements in Θ(log n) time. So is the answer O(1) considering input size n?

I have also seen a different explanation which derives the complexity as Θ(log n/log log n) considering input size logn. I don't quite follow this method either. So which is the correct answer and why ?

Comment: Can someone enlighten me how the title can make sense? The complexity is a function of number of elements (size of the input), how can you ask, how many you can sort? It sounds like asking what is (the biggest) `x` for `f(x)`. PS. I assumed "How many number of elements" is "How many elements".

Comment: "How many number of elements can be sorted in Θ(log n) time using heap sort?" does not make any sense to me.

Comment: I think the answer is "n".

Comment: Sorting `log(n)` elements of a list is just useless. The fastest sorting methods for a list of `n` elements take `O(n)` and only work in special cases...

Comment: @Codie I think the answer is `0` or `1`. Cuz' you cannot sort faster than `n log n` with heap sort, so maybe some zero-like border-case input would do the trick.

Comment: Whenever you put a bound on the problem size you can solve it in O(1). I.e. constant time, large enough to accommodate the largest possible problem.

Comment: @luk32 Right, didn't notice he had `log n`, not `n log n`.

Comment: You will have to solve the equation log(n) = klog(k). Solve for k.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the question is "assuming that there is a known value of n somewhere, what is the asymptotic bound on the size of an array, as a function of n, where sorting that array with heapsort will take time Θ(log n)?"

Sorting an array with k elements takes time Θ(k log k) as k grows. You want to choose k such that Θ(k log k) = Θ(log n). Choosing k = Θ(log n) doesn't necessarily work, since Θ(k log k) = Θ(log n log log n) ≠ Θ(log n). On the other hand, if you choose k = Θ(log n / log log n), then the runtime of the sort will be

> Θ((log n / log log n) log (log n / log log n))
>
> = Θ((log n / log log n) (log log n - log log log n))
>
> = Θ(log n - log n log log log n / log log n)
>
> = Θ(log n (1 - log log log n / log log n))

Notice that 1 - log log log n / log log n tends toward 1 as n goes to infinity, so the above expression actually is Θ(log n), as required.

Therefore, if you try to sort an array of size Θ(log n / log log n) using heap sort, as a function of n, the runtime is Θ(log n).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Pretty good answer. But can you tell me why unitary method fails here ? For n elements, it takes nlogn time. So if it takes logn time, then number of elements is (n)(logn)/nlogn which is 1. What is the flaw in this approach?

Comment: I'm not sure I see how you're deriving that second ratio. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @templatetypedef I am not deriving anything. I am just using unitary method which says if X units takes Y time units then Z units will take (ZY)/X time units which doesn't work here. I am not able to find the reason for that.

Comment: Ok, I got it now why this naive method of division doesn't work. This method works only when the graph (or the function) has a slope 1 (or makes 45 degrees with x axis) like y=x or y=2x. If suppose an algorithm takes 2n time units with n as number of inputs then we can apply this method but here the logn part in nlogn spoils everything.

Answer (score 0):

to sort N elements, time = O(NlogN)
that basically means, sorting each element will take O(logN) time

Comment: "sorting each element" just sounds / is wrong. Perhaps you want to say "you need to do (on average) O(log n) work per element". But anyway, OP already knows that heapsort takes O(n log n) time, so this doesn't really add any information.

Comment: well the way i understand it is that, every time you insert an element into a heap to a sorted position takes O(logN) time. In here, one element can also be interpreted as constant number of elements.

Comment: If there's no elements in the heap yet, you only need to do O(1) work to insert an element, so you definitely need an "on average" somewhere there. And you can't really say you're sorting an element because that implies (at least to me) either that you're sorting the actual element (as in you have, for example, an array of arrays, and you're sorting one of the arrays, as opposed to the array of arrays) or that sorting can be done on a per-element basis, without having to care about any of the other elements, which is exactly what sorting isn't.

Comment: i thought the big O notation automatically ignore small cases.